# ViewPager and fragment error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Why isn't this working? I get an error on setContentView and findViewById.

The Method is undefined for the type Utesteder.

If there is anything more infromation you need, please ask!

I am pretty new at app developing.

```
package hib.bergen2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Utesteder extends Fragment {


    TextView exodusTekst;
    Button exodusKnapp;

    TextView fotballpubenTekst;
    Button fotballpubenKnapp;

    TextView ovenpoTekst;
    Button ovenpoKnapp;

    TextView kvarteretTekst;
    Button kvarteretKnapp;

    TextView hulenTekst;
    Button hulenKnapp;

    TextView sjobodenTekst;
    Button sjobodenKnapp;

    TextView downstairsTekst;
    Button downstairsKnapp;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_utesteder);



        exodusTekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exodusTekst);

        exodusKnapp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.exodusKnapp);
        exodusKnapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                exodusTekst.setVisibility((exodusTekst.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                fotballpubenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ovenpoTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                kvarteretTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hulenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sjobodenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                downstairsTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });

        fotballpubenTekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fotballpubenTekst);

        fotballpubenKnapp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.fotballpubenKnapp);
        fotballpubenKnapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                fotballpubenTekst.setVisibility((fotballpubenTekst.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                exodusTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ovenpoTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                kvarteretTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hulenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sjobodenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                downstairsTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });

        ovenpoTekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ovenpoTekst);

        ovenpoKnapp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.ovenpoKnapp);
        ovenpoKnapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                ovenpoTekst.setVisibility((ovenpoTekst.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                exodusTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fotballpubenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                kvarteretTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hulenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sjobodenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                downstairsTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });

        kvarteretTekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kvarteretTekst);

        kvarteretKnapp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.kvarteretKnapp);
        kvarteretKnapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                kvarteretTekst.setVisibility((kvarteretTekst.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                exodusTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fotballpubenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ovenpoTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hulenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sjobodenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                downstairsTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });

        hulenTekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hulenTekst);

        hulenKnapp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.hulenKnapp);
        hulenKnapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                hulenTekst.setVisibility((hulenTekst.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                exodusTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fotballpubenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ovenpoTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                kvarteretTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sjobodenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                downstairsTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });

        sjobodenTekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sjobodenTekst);

        sjobodenKnapp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.sjobodenKnapp);
        sjobodenKnapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                sjobodenTekst.setVisibility((sjobodenTekst.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                exodusTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fotballpubenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ovenpoTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                kvarteretTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hulenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                downstairsTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });

        downstairsTekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.downstairsTekst);

        downstairsKnapp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.downstairsKnapp);
        downstairsKnapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                downstairsTekst.setVisibility((downstairsTekst.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                exodusTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fotballpubenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ovenpoTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                kvarteretTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hulenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sjobodenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });
    }

}




     package hib.bergen2;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Uteliv extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_uteliv);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.uteliv, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }



        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int page) {
            switch (page) {
                case 0: return new Utesteder();
                /*case 1: return new MySecondFragment();
                case 2: return new MyThirdFragment();
                //and so on....*/
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uteliv_dummy,
                    container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Utesteder extends Fragment {

 //...

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_utesteder,
            container, false);
            exodusTekst = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.exodusTekst);
            //and so on.. 

         }
 }
```

**Note: its not just findViewById, its v.findViewById();**

Answer (score 1):

`setContentView` is a method of `Activity` not of `Fragment`. `onCreateView` have to return the view you want to show